# Connection fails just after winning a battle in Adventure Mode. How can I know if I received the cards?

Tags: hearthstone

The battle ended, and then, game froze and I was taken to main screen. Nothing was said about the 2 cards I should receive after the battle.

**Additional info:**
The next battle is avaliable and I have the Mad Scientist card(which is supposed to be the prize), but it's not marked as new (and I don't remember if I already had it) .

Comment: Check in your card collection?

Comment: What was the fight or who did you fight?

Comment: @Sorean, GROBBULUS, the second boss of Construct district

Comment: You could either check whether the next Adventure Mode mission is avaialble (unless it was the final boss of a wing), or check the wiki or another source to see which cards you should have (I'd imagine they would be marked as "new" cards either way).

Comment: The next battle is avaliable and I have the Mad Scientist card(which is supposed to be the prize), but it's not marked as new (and I don't remember if I already had it)

Comment: Yeah the next battle is the best indicator that you got credit for beating the boss.

Comment: @MarceloAssis if you have more information relating to the question please include it in your question instead of in a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your card collection for the [Mad Scientist](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Mad_Scientist) card. That is the reward from the fight if you completed it. If the next fight is available in adventure mode then that also indicates that you completed the previous fight. You just missed the animation/notification of the cards you get/got.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell by the big green V on the boss' icon. If it's marked as completed, you will always get the cards.

Your card collection is stored on Blizzard's servers, not on your local device. Your client freezing will not prevent you from getting the rewards. As long as you can see the match ending, it's safe to assume that everything is in place.